# Processing a queue of arrays

Tags: c++, stl, queue, std

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

void addSomeContent(queue<TCHAR*> &s)
{
    static int counter=0;
    TCHAR buffer[30];

    wsprintf(buffer,TEXT("foo%d"),counter);

    s.push(buffer);
    counter++;

    if(counter < 10)
    addSomeContent(s);
}


int main (void)
{
    queue<TCHAR*> strings; 

    addSomeContent(strings);

    while(!strings.empty()) 
    {   
        wcout<<strings.front()<<endl;
        strings.pop();
    }

    system("pause");
    return (0);
}
```

Output:

> foo0
>  ♦

Desired:

> foo0
>  foo1
>  .
>  .
>  .
>  foo9

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that your `buffer` is a local variale on stack. Once you leave the function, it will expire.

If you really want to do this way, create it on heap `TCHAR *buffer = new TCHAR[30];`. And you might need to `delete[]` it after some point.

However, I think using some built-in types or stl containers instead of manipulating pointers will make your code more readable and manageable.

Answer (score 1):

when you do

```
s.push(buffer);
```

you add the pointer to `buffer` to the queue several times (you would get identical copies of the last string in the best case), but that pointer will is invalid once you reach the end of `addSomeContent` (giving you a random content if not a segmentation violation). You should add a copy of the string to the queue.

Comment: 'counter is never increased, expect one string only'. Are you sure?

Comment: 'You should add a copy of the string to the queue.' - How to implement this? `s.push(*buffer);` doesn't work.

Comment: if you really have to use pointers to chars, use [`strdup`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html) possibly in combination with `auto_ptr` as filipenf suggests or [`shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#example). But this all is done for you behind the scenes if you use `std::string`.

Comment: I agree with Andre, the best option is to use std::string and do the casts to TCHAR whenever you need.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the TCHAR pointer is in the stack. For you to pass the pointer out of the function you should allocate it in the heap ( with new ).

But why are you using TCHAR instead of std::string?

Comment: I use TCHAR because it's more "seamless" with Windows API.

Comment: So you should use xvatar's suggestion of allocating it using new TCHAR[...]. But you'll have to delete it after the use of the queue, or you will have to wrap it in a std::auto_ptr or something like that... Or... you use std::string :-)

Comment: `std::auto_ptr` - I've never heard about this utility. Thanks, it would be very useful.